# Azure AD Authentication with Angular issue calling back-end

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal

I have been trying to set up an Angular SPA with ADAL authentication following this guide: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-microsoft-adal-for-angular-6-with-configurable-settings/

Upon following through with it, I had a few minor issues which I worked around (i.e. I could not load app config from local json because the interceptor described in the article intercepts my call to the json and fails as adal-angular is not loaded yet). But that's another problem - I worked around it by hard coding my config for now.

The issue now is that, after successfully signing in to Microsoft and being redirected to my app, calls to my back end fail with "this.adal.GetResourceForEndpoint is not a function". This is where the error happens:
[image: Error location and code]

I can see in the debugger that the function is indeed not defined, along with "isAuthenticated" and "acquireToken" which should be defined as per the imported service:
[image: Adal import with function definitions]

I really don't know what I might be doing wrong and why/how these functions are not defined, especially after successfully signing in. Any ADAL experts to help out?

Here's the relevant setup code:

```
//APP.MODULE.TS--------------------------------------------
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";
import {
  MsAdalAngular6Module,
  MsAdalAngular6Service,
  AuthenticationGuard
} from "microsoft-adal-angular6";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DashboardModule } from "./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module";
import { AppConfig } from "./app.config";
import { InsertAuthTokenInterceptor } from "./insert-auth-token-interceptor";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

let adalConfig: any; // will be initialized by APP_INITIALIZER
export function msAdalAngular6ConfigFactory() {
  return adalConfig; // will be invoked later when creating MsAdalAngular6Service
}

// refer to:
// https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/
// for a description of the AppConfig service
export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  const promise = appConfig.load().then(() => {
    adalConfig = {
      tenant: AppConfig.settings.adalConfig.tenant,
      clientId: AppConfig.settings.adalConfig.clientId,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      endpoints: AppConfig.settings.adalConfig.endpoints,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
      cacheLocation: AppConfig.settings.adalConfig.cacheLocation
    };
  });
  return () => promise;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DashboardModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsAdalAngular6Module
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfig,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppConfig],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: "adalConfig",
      useFactory: msAdalAngular6ConfigFactory,
      deps: []
    },
    MsAdalAngular6Service,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InsertAuthTokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: ["adalConfig"]
    },
    AuthenticationGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

//APP.CONFIG.TS-----------------------------------------------
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";
import { IAppConfig } from "./app-config.model";
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  static settings: IAppConfig;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  load() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>{
        env: {
          name: "dev"
        },
        adalConfig: {
          clientId: "xxx",
          tenant: "xxx",
          cacheLocation: "localStorage",
          endpoints: {
            api: "xxx"
          }
        }
      };
      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with `constructor(private adalSvc: MsAdalAngular6Service) {
    console.log(this.adalSvc.userInfo);
    var token = this.adalSvc.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com').subscribe((token: string) => {
      console.log(token);
    });;
  }`  Here is a working sample https://github.com/manishrasrani/ms-adal-angular6-example

Comment: If I just do the constructor code you gave, I get an "undefined" and "acquireToken is not a function". The code from the sample does not use app initializer as the article I followed, it uses hardcoded configuration which I was trying to avoid

Comment: I abandoned the use of APP_INITIALIZER and was able to make it work by directly initializing the module with "forRoot" and hardcoded config in environment.ts. Not an ideal solution and doesn't really explain the problem described so I wouldn't consider it an actual answer...